# Unknown type "struct"

Tags: c, gcc, struct, compiler-errors

I'm having issue compiling my code. I think it has something to do with include but I don't understand I used `#ifend; #endif`. I think I know why but I don't understand why the ifend & endif is now working as I want to. I feel like it is because I have some kind of include recursion. But I don't get why #ifend #endif is not working.

[Github](https://github.com/RaiZiStyle/RogueLike) if want to try to compile it by yourself.

game.h

```
#ifendef GAME_H
typedef struct Position{
    int x;
    int y;
    // TILE_TYPE tile;
}Position;

typedef struct Room{
    Position position;
    int height;
    int width;
    // Monster **monster;
    // Item **item;
}Room;
#endif
```

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include "../header/game.h"



typedef struct Player{
    Position position;
    int health;
    // Room *room;
} Player;
Player *playerSetup();
int playerMove(int y, int x, Player *user);


#endif
```

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "../header/player.h"
#include "../header/screen.h"

typedef struct Position{
    int x;
    int y;
    // TILE_TYPE tile;
}Position;

typedef struct Room{
    Position position;
    int height;
    int width;
    // Monster **monster;
    // Item **item;
}Room;

int handleInput(int input, Player *user);
int checkPosition(int newY, int newX, Player *unit);
#endif
```

Error throw by gcc

```
gcc -o Obj/player.o -c src/player.c -Wall
In file included from src/../header/../header/game.h:4,
                 from src/../header/player.h:6,
                 from src/player.c:1:
src/../header/../header/../header/screen.h:7:1: error: unknown type name ‘Room’
    7 | Room **mapSetup();
      | ^~~~
src/../header/../header/../header/screen.h:8:1: error: unknown type name ‘Room’
    8 | Room *createRoom(int x, int y, int height, int width);
      | ^~~~
src/../header/../header/../header/screen.h:9:14: error: unknown type name ‘Room’
    9 | int drawRoom(Room *room);
      |              ^~~~
In file included from src/../header/player.h:6,
                 from src/player.c:1:
src/../header/../header/game.h:20:28: error: unknown type name ‘Player’
   20 | int handleInput(int input, Player *user);
      |                            ^~~~~~
src/../header/../header/game.h:21:39: error: unknown type name ‘Player’
   21 | int checkPosition(int newY, int newX, Player *unit);
      |                                       ^~~~~~
make: *** [makefile:19: Obj/player.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What does this macro #ifendef GAME_H mean?

Comment: Is `#ifendef` a typo? Did you mean [`#ifndef`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional) (which stands for "if not defined")?

Comment: #ifendef is typo, I wanted to type #ifndef

Comment: In your question, you have posted two different code snippets that both claim to represent the file contents of `game.h`. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got recursive dependencies.  game.h includes player.h and player.h includes game.h.  With the include guards this means that only one of them will include the other, but this also means that one will be missing something it needs.

Both game.h and player.h are dependent on `Position`, so move that into its own header that both game.h and player.h include.

Comment: Yea but I don't want to move Position into a new file, I thought #ifndef, #endif was enough to get ride of recursive dependencies.

Comment: @RaiZy_Style Then you'll need to put `Position`, `Room`, and `Player` in the same file.

Comment: Isnt there an other solution ? I thought I #ifndef was enough

Comment: @RaiZy_Style That prevents recursive inclusion, but 1) the two files are dependent on each other, and 2) they duplicate a definition.  `Position` must be defined in exactly one  place in a given translation unit (i.e. a .c file and all the headers it includes).

Comment: The size of Position must be known at the point you use one in either Room or Player, so it must be defined before either of those structs can be defined.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I need to make sure position is declare before both Room and Player ?

Comment: @RaiZy_Style Yes, because it's needed by both.

Comment: And how do I do that witouth creating a new file that contain those struct ? Sorry I'm a bit new to c.

Comment: @RaiZy_Style Put all 3 in one file.

Comment: Isn't there an other solution than put every struct on the same file ? Sorry if I'm too picky but I don't like the solution you gave me. But thanks for the help tho

Comment: @RaiZy_Style You can either put them all in one file or put `Position` in one file and have the other two include.  Those are your options.

Comment: Ok, so i have change a bit my code, but i'm still facing the same issue but this time it's with the Player struct. 
ps: i have updated my github, feel free to see the change i have made and give me advices if you want to :)

Comment: @RaiZy_Style You still have a recursive dependency.  Put all of the structs in one header, then have game.h and player.h include that header.  Then they won't depend on each other.  That's how I would structure it.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to create a new file that contains all my struct. I'm too picky sorry 